# Contour Detection of Low-Contrast Swarm Front Using Python Open CV

Tags: python, opencv

I am new to using Open CV in Python and have what seems to be a basic question. I am trying to emphasize the border around a bacterial swarm which appears as an opaque growth on the surface of a petri dish (see Figure 1A). The problem is that it is very low-contrast.

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBaK2.jpg)

[Image for processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBdJ4.jpg)

```
import cv2 as cv

swarm = cv.imread('swarm2.jpg')
swarm_gray = cv.cvtColor(swarm, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv.threshold(swarm_gray, 70, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv.drawContours(swarm, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

cv.imshow('Swarm', swarm) 
cv.imshow('Swarm Gray', swarm_gray)
  
cv.waitKey(0) 
cv.destroyAllWindows() 

cv.imwrite('Contours.jpg', swarm)
```

The code itself is very simple and consists of converting the image to grayscale, applying a threshold, and then identifying contours (see the code output). Figure 1B shows what I would like the code to produce and Figure 1C is what the code is currently producing. As you can see, the results are less than ideal. The end-goal of this pursuit is to be able to measure the area of the growth using python in an automated fashion. Any thoughts on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try some morphology after thresholdind  to first remove the small dots and then dilate to fill the result out to some larger shape.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. A lot of the terms you have used I am not familiar with...

Comment: Search Google for examples. For example, see https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html